# How do I make a contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I want to Make a contact form in wordpress including input fields and some checkboxes , I want the form data to go to my email address.
How do I make one from scratch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the wordpress dashboard and click "Contact" on the left hand side.

Click add new.

In this area you have two boxes, form and mail. Form is what is displayed on your website and mail generates what is sent to you (ie the e-mail address the form will be sent to and the default template of that e-mail).

Directing mail to your e-mail address is very simple - just change the "To" box to your e-mail.

The form box is completed by generating tags using the plugin. For example, to generate a file upload box you click generate tag -> file upload -> and change the options within (required field, etc) and then paste the given code to the form and the mail boxes where it directs you to.

Once this process is finished for all forms click save and copy the generated shortcode to the page you want to include this contact form in.

Hope this answers your question,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can find all you need in their documentation.

[Contact Form 7 Documentation](http://contactform7.com/text-fields/)